# F# Generic IDictionary extension failed

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

When I try to extend IDictionary with the following code

```
type Generic.IDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue> with
    member this.GetOrAdd (key:'TKey, fun':'TKey -> 'TValue) =
        match this.ContainsKey(key) with
        | true -> this.Item(key)
        | false -> 
            let val_ = fun' key
            this.Add(key, val_)
            val_

let dd = dict[(1,2); (3,4)]
let f = fun x -> 2*x
let d5 = dd.GetOrAdd(5, f)
```

I got the following error in runtime.

> System.NotSupportedException: Exception of type >'System.NotSupportedException' was thrown.
>     at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.ExtraTopLevelOperators.dictValueType@98.System->Collections-Generic-IDictionary`2-Add(TKey key, T value)
>      at FSI_0011.IDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue](IDictionary`2 this, >TKey key, FSharpFunc`2 fun') in >D:\BaiduYunDownload\DroiEtl\Droi.MyToPG\Util.Sync.fs:line 259
>     at .$FSI_0018.main@() in >D:\BaiduYunDownload\DroiEtl\Droi.MyToPG\Util.Sync.fs:line 264
>   Stopped due to error

But the compiler doesn't complain when building...
Please help me...

Comment: It would be slightly faster to use `TryGetValue` instead of `ContainsKey` because the "already exists" code path would only have to do one dictionary lookup, instead of the two lookups you're doing now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dict` [is documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/extratopleveloperators.dict%5B'key,'value%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) to return a *read-only* `IDictionary<_,_>` – you then call `.Add` on it, and the backing class rightly throws an exception.

Create a real `Dictionary` instance instead and you'll see it works as expected:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type IDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue> with
    member this.GetOrAdd (key:'TKey, fun':'TKey -> 'TValue) =
        match this.ContainsKey key with
          | true  -> this.Item key
          | false -> let val' = fun' key
                     this.Add (key, val')
                     val'

let dd =
    let d = Dictionary()
    d.Add (1, 2)
    d.Add (3, 4)
    d

printfn "%A" dd
dd.GetOrAdd (5, (fun x -> 2 * x)) |> printfn "%A :: %d" dd
dd.GetOrAdd (5, (fun x -> 9 * x)) |> printfn "%A :: %d" dd
```

Output:

```
seq [[1, 2]; [3, 4]]
seq [[1, 2]; [3, 4]; [5, 10]] :: 10
seq [[1, 2]; [3, 4]; [5, 10]] :: 10
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://ideone.com/z7NFm8)</kbd>

Implementation-wise, @JoelMueller's suggestion is an obvious improvement:

```
type IDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue> with
    member this.GetOrAdd (key:'TKey, fun':'TKey -> 'TValue) =
        match this.TryGetValue key with
          | true, val' -> val'
          | false, _   -> let val' = fun' key
                          this.Add (key, val')
                          val'
```